# WDS contribution prizes location?

Tags: planetside-2

I got a 5 pack of camo and for the life of me cannot find where they are. I have checked all my classes and weapons and nothing shows up. I have also checked my steam inventory if for some reason they showed there. Feel like it shouldn't be all that hard to find.

Comment: Mine are accessible through weapon customisation, as camouflage. However, I'm fairly sure I should have more than 8 after completing tier 2 contribution twice. I don't why I can't find some of them, either.

Answer (score 1):

To apply on-time-use camo you have to use the 'customize' screen, rather then the camo arrow selector.

Your camo may be vehicle, armor, or weapon camo. I found that I had vehicle camo.